# Websphere Application Server SAML Token processing

Tags: java, websphere, saml, websphere-7, websphere-8

I'm able to successfully setup websphere to authenticate with an IdP and access the web resource as expected. But now my application needs the claims/assertions/attributes available in the SAML token/response to proceed further. What is best option available to access the SAML response/attributes inside my java application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to add to the previous answer.For Websphere Application Server, if you are using already available WebsphereSamlSP application as SP then you can use following code inside `handleRedirect()` method of `IBMWebpshereSamlACSListenerServlet` to get saml attributes. Or use this in your custom SP code.

```
SAMLToken samlToken = (SAMLToken) AccessController
                        .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
                            public Object run() throws java.lang.Exception {
                                final java.util.Iterator authIterator = subject
                                        .getPrivateCredentials(SAMLToken.class)
                                        .iterator();
                                if (authIterator.hasNext()) {
                                    final SAMLToken token = (SAMLToken) authIterator
                                            .next();
                                    return token;
                                }
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
            // Log attribute name and values
                List<SAMLAttribute> attributes = samlToken.getSAMLAttributes();
                if (attributes != null && !attributes.isEmpty()) {
                    for (SAMLAttribute attr : attributes) {
                        logger.debug(attr.getName());
                        if (attr.getStringAttributeValue() != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < attr.getStringAttributeValue().length; i++) {
                                logger.debug(attr.getStringAttributeValue()[i]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

For WebSphere Liberty profile:

1. get com.ibm.websphere.security.saml2.Saml20Token from RunAsSubject:

   ```
   Saml20Token samlToken = null;
   Subject subject = WSSubject.getRunAsSubject();
   Iterator authIterator = subject.getPrivateCredentials(Saml20Token.class).iterator();
   if (authIterator.hasNext()) {
       samlToken = (Saml20Token) authIterator.next();
   }
   ```
2. You can get List of com.ibm.websphere.security.saml2.Saml20Attribute from Saml20Token

   samlToken.getSAMLAttributes();
3. You can also get most SAML assertions from Saml20Token. For example
      samlToken.getSAMLIssuerName();

For classic WebSphere:

```
    Subject subject = WSSubject.getRunAsSubject();
    SAMLToken samlToken = (SAMLToken) AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
                    public Object run() throws java.lang.Exception
                    {
                        final java.util.Iterator authIterator = subject.getPrivateCredentials(SAMLToken.class).iterator();
                        if ( authIterator.hasNext() ) {
                            final SAMLToken token = (SAMLToken) authIterator.next();
                            return token;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
                   SAMLNameID = samlToken.getSAMLNameID();
    List<SAMLAttribute>  attributes = samlToken.getSAMLAttributes();
```

Comment: Do you know how to configure server.xml in OpenLiberty and which dependencies should I include in pom.xml. Now it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/websphere/security/saml2/Saml20Token`